# Upload File to Google-drive Teamdrive folder with PyDrive

Tags: python, python-3.4, pydrive, google-drive-shared-drive

I have been successfully uploading files to a google-drive-folder with PyDrive. But, when it comes to uploading files to a folder in a google-drive-teamdrive-folder which is shared with me, the following code is not working.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


location_to_save = "D:\images"
mImageLoc =  location_to_save + "\\abcd.jpg"

#[...Code to fetch and save the file as abcd.jpg ...]

gfolder_id = "1H1gjBKcpiHJtnXKVxWQEC1CS8t4Gswjj"  #This is a google drive folder id. I am replacing this with a teamdrive folder id, but that does not work
gfile_title = mImageLoc.split("\\")[-1] # returns abcd.jpg

http = gdrive.auth.Get_Http_Object()
f = gdrive.CreateFile({"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": gfolder_id}],
                                   'title': gfile_title})
            f.SetContentFile(mImageLoc)
            f.Upload(param={"http": http})
```

The error message I am recieving is: `pydrive.files.ApiRequestError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "File not found: 0AG-N4DqGC1nbUk9PVA">`
'0AG-N4DqGC1nbUk9PVA' is the teamdrive's folder id here.

I have been searching for means to upload files to Teamdrives with PyDrive but in vain. I see in the pydrive's github pages that they added the teamdrives support approx 8 month ago. But I cannot find any documentation on how to use that. Can anyone suggest where I am being wrong please?

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: Yes, the solution from David Lloyd worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For uploading, try making a file called "settings.yaml" and saving it in your working directory, as per the instructions here:
https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html

You will need the client id and client secret found in the client_secrets.json file which should also be in your directory after you authorised access to the Google API.

Test it out with the following code to make a text file in a folder in the team drive:

```
parent_folder_id = 'YYYY'

f = drive.CreateFile({
    'title': 'test.txt',
    'parents': [{
        'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
        'teamDriveId': team_drive_id,
        'id': parent_folder_id
    }]
})
f.SetContentString('Hello World')

f.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})

# where XXXX and YYYY are the team drive and target folder ids found from the end of the URLS when you open them in your browser.
```