# uploading a image to Google Drive shared folder but can't manage to make the image appear as a jpg in google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, jpeg, mime-types

I am using this code from [Upload File to Google-drive Teamdrive folder with PyDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267728/upload-file-to-google-drive-teamdrive-folder-with-pydrive/55065483#55065483?newreg=147a43b843dc464a85f74ca675475e1c) from David Lloyd response, but after running his code I am unable to change the mimeType to image/jpg. I have tried add in my code like so:

```
parent_folder_id = 'YYYY'

f = drive.CreateFile({
    'title': 'image.jpg', 'mimeType': 'image/jpg'
    'parents': [{
        'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
        'teamDriveId': team_drive_id,
        'id': parent_folder_id
    }]
})
f.SetContentString("path/image.jpg")

f.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})

# where XXXX and YYYY are the team drive and target folder ids found from the end of the URLS when you open them in your browser.
```

but the image uploads as a PDF file in Google Drive.

Comment: Have you considered using the official [Drive API Client](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/) for Python provided by Google?

Comment: I tried using, but couldn't make it work using the official(I am new to GoogleApi and programming, so to code in the API learned through PyDrive because I found easier to code in it). But what I am frustrated is that this mimetype works when uploading to My Drive but not to the Shared Folder.

Comment: I have changed the mimeType to image/jpeg. It appears as a image in google drive, but it doesn't give me a preview and when I download it says the file is damage. Any idea of may have caused this?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you this solution, which uses the [Python Client Library for Drive](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) and modifying one part of the [Drive Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)'s code. I was able to upload an image into a Shared Drive in a specific folder and also changing the mimeType from `png` to `jpg`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # This is all the metadata for the file
    file_metadata = {
        "name": "testupload.jpg",
        # My shared Drive id
        "driveId": "you-shared-drive-id",
        "parents": [
            #Folder where the file will be saved
            "folder-id"
        ]
    }
    # This is all the file's data
    media = MediaFileUpload('testupload.png', mimetype='image/jpg')
    # This is all the file's data 
    file_upload = service.files().create(
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        supportsTeamDrives=True,
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media
    ).execute()

    print(file_upload)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: my code doesn't understand the MediaFileUpload, even though I have apiclient dowloaded

Comment: I am also having trouble with the token verification, that is located in the same folder as the code

Comment: Did you install using pip all libraries in the [step 2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_2_install_the_google_client_library) ? What error is being thrown when you try to use the token?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the SetContentString() to SetContentFile() it works to upload images to Team Drives. So the code would look like this:

```
parent_folder_id = 'YYYY'

f = drive.CreateFile({
    'title': 'image.jpg', 'mimeType': 'image/jpg'
    'parents': [{
        'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
        'teamDriveId': team_drive_id,
        'id': parent_folder_id
    }]
})
f.SetContentFile("path/image.jpg")

f.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})

# where XXXX and YYYY are the team drive and target folder ids found from the end of the URLS when you open them in your browser.
```